# Calculation using jquery onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-selectors

I have this type of exercise in jquery. Go here http://jsfiddle.net/LAntL/3/

For `Item 1`, if I add #no of quantity of `Size 7`, it should be `multiplied by Item 1's Price` displayed in text box and the result should be shown in `Item 1's Ext` textbox.
then if I do same for `size 8.5 of Item 1`, it should perform the same.

But the Ext will have `(Price x Size 7 Qty) + (Price x Size 8.5 Qty)`

Same will happen for `Item 2`. And along with this, `Total quantity and Total price` will be updated on `keypress` event of each textbox.

I'm a beginner in jquery and got this killing exercise.
Please help someone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you assign some classes to your fields so that jQuery can easily find them:

```
"lineQty"   - add this class to all the qty fields
"lineTotal" - add this class to all the line total fields
"linePrice" - I think you can see where I'm going with this
"lineExt"   - add to all ext fields
```

Then the following `.keyup` function will do the updates on *all* lines automatically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".lineQty").keyup(function() {
       // 'this' is the field the user is typing in
       // so find the tr that it belongs to
       var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),
           total = 0,
           // get the price for the current row:
           price = $row.find(".linePrice").val();

        // loop through every qty field for the current row and add
        // the entered value to the total, using unary plus to convert
        // to a number, and a default of 0 if non-numeric data is entered
        $row.find(".lineQty").each(function() {
            total += +this.value || 0;
        });

        // set the total for the current row
        $row.find(".lineTotal").val(total);

        // set the price for the current row
        $row.find(".lineExt").val(total * price);

        // now add up the grand totals
        var grandTotal = 0,
            grandPrice = 0;
         $(".lineTotal").each(function() {
           grandTotal += +this.value || 0;
        });
        $(".lineExt").each(function() {
            grandPrice += +this.value || 0;
        });
        $("[name='data[totalQuantity]']").val(grandTotal);
        $("[name='data[totalPrice]']").val(grandPrice);
    }); 

});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LAntL/5/ (only works on the first line because I couldn't be bothered assigning classes to *all* your fields - you would need to add the classes I talk about above to every field as per what I did for the first line).

Comment: Hey nnnnnn, Thanks. I have little modified this to make my module working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you want to learn something, so I will describe a possible way, and don't give you the finished solution.

First of all, you should mark the tables which contains items with `class="item"`. Now you can write a selector in jQuery which gets every item separately. Then you should mark all cells (`<td>`) which have a special function. Total, Price, Disc and Ext. Your table should look like this:

```
<table class="item">
  <tr>
    <td>...</td>

    <td class="total">...</td>
    <td class="price">...</td>
    <td class="disc">...</td>
    <td class="ext">...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now you can write a selector for all input fields inside of the table with class "item".

```
$('.item input').change(function(){});
```

Inside of this function you can handle the calculation. At first I would recommend to get the item:

```
$('.item input').change(function(){
   var item = $(this).closest('table.item');
   var totalInput = $(item).find('.total input');
   var priceInput = $(item).price('.price input');
   // ...

   var allWriteableInputs = $(item).find('input[readonly!="readonly"]');

   // do the calculation
   var sum = 0;
   $(allWriteableInputs).each(function(i, input){
       sum += $(input).val();
   });
   $(totalInput).val(sum);
});
```

If you go this way, you don't need:

1. The `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"` and
2. the `id="product1Total"` for every inputbox

I hope this thought-provoking impulse helps you a little bit. You have still a long way to go, my young padawan ;-)